# Помогите правильно сверстать

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: пример]

[image: пример при наведении]

Есть такой макет. Необходимо правильно сверстать блоки, чтобы при наведении можно было давать границам тени, в том числе и на срезанном участке сверху Пробовал перекрывать квадратный блок круглым, но не совпадали границы, провобал класть картинку с границами на фон, но тогда нужна четкая высота, что не хорошо при адаптивности. Может есть еще решения. Спасибо

Comment: И на будущее, добавляй код, людям гадать, как и чем ты срезал блоки, и что у тебя не получается

Comment: добавьте [mcve]